# How to resolve "abandoned transaction" when I use "hg push"?

Tags: mercurial, sourceforge

We work with a *sourceforge* project. When we try to push, then mercurial abort :

```
$ hg push

pushing to ssh://<user>@hg.code.sf.net/p/loremipsum/code
searching for changes
remote: abort: abandoned transaction found - run hg recover!
abort: unexpected response: empty string
```

And when we try to recover that doesn't work :

```
$ hg recover
no interrupted transaction available
```

The other programmers of the project have the same problem. We are a lost.

Comment: This looks like the problem is on the remote end... are there any tools provided by SF to manage the remote repository? Or perhaps use the `-R` to specify the repository to perform the recover on (i.e. `hg recover -R ssh://<user>@hg.code.sf.net/p/loremipsum/code`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I try :
$hg recover -R ssh://<user>@hg.code.sf.net/p/loremipsum/code, I have : "abandon : the repository is not local".

Comment: I was afraid of that, looks like this needs to be resolved by SourceForge. If it's an option, you could create a new repository to push all the changes to in order for your team to continue working.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In my case I had to run

```
hg recover
```

on the **remote** machine to which I was pushing to. It fixed the problems and I could push the changes from my machine.

Comment: I didn't have hg installed on my remote server but running this worked: `hg recover -R \\UNC\path\to\repository`

Answer (score 4):

You can login to sourceforge by ssh (https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Shell%20Service/). Go into your hg folder, e.g. /home/hg/p/YOURPROJECTNAME/code, run `hg recover` here. Then everything's OK.

Comment: The last directory step is not always `/code`, but the mount point you can choose on allura.  (it was `/hg` in my case, because `/code` was still svn)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **bitbucket.com** **cloud** solution and you get this error you need to open a ticket so they will run `hg recover` on their server.

They are very fast at answering tickets of this variety.